# how to set max size for imagecreatetruecolor in PHP

Tags: php

When i create image like:

```
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(1700, 1200);
```

the image is created normal but when i set size abow 2000x2000 it could not created. How to change the limit value. I have a godaddy ultimate hosting. I have changed in PHP5.ini memory_limit = 300M but does not effect.

the my working code is:

```
$in_filename = "image/".$img3[6];

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($in_filename);


$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('tsomog/'.$img3[6]);


list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dest);

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('tsomog1/'.$img3[6]);

 list($width1, $height1) = getimagesize($src);



$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(1700, 1200);

$white = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopy ($new_image, $src , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,$new_width1, $new_height1);
imagecopy ($new_image, $dest , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,$new_width, $new_height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new_image,"tsomog2/".$img3[6]);
imagedestroy($new_image);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

the $in_filename filesze is abow 2000x2000

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is not an issue of maxsize of `imagecreatetruecolor`. The issue here seems to be the memory allocation. Try and talk to your web hosting provider to get the memory increased,